# Как передать id button-а из html в js объект?

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуста. Имею такую ситуацию, есть две кнопки с разными id в HTML файлe, мне нужно взять все id всех кнопок с классом .btn и передать их в внешний объект в js, к которому я могу получить доступ, но как всё это реализовать не понимаю. Мне потом этот объект нужен, чтобы из него извлекать id для поиска.
Любая помощь будет полезна, заранее спасибо.

HTML файл

```
<ul>
   <li><button id="but1">ButtonOne</button></li>
   <li><button id="but2">ButtonTwo</button></li> 
</ul>
```

JS конечный файл

```
objData = {
  id: but1,
  id: but2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var buttons = [];

/*$("button.btn").each(function(){
  buttons.push({ id: this.id });
});*/

document.querySelectorAll("button.btn").forEach(
  btn => buttons.push({ id: btn.id })
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(buttons));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><button id="but1" class="btn">ButtonOne</button></li>
   <li><button id="but2" class="btn">ButtonTwo</button></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: ну и `script src` в комменты тогда

Comment: Огромное спасибо, мне удалось найти решение, вот как оно выглядит.

const objData = [...document.getElementsByClassName('btn-view')].reduce((a, c, i ) =>
(a['H' + i + ' - h ' + i] = {name: c.name, id: c.id}, a), {});
console.log(objData);

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk Молодец! Желаю дальнейших успехов.

Comment: Это братья из toster-a помогли. =)

Answer (score 4):

### MDN

[HTMLButtonElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) Наследует свойства от его родителя, [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) - используется для получения всех элементов с классом `.btn` в виде [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

[Конвертирование_NodeList_в_Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_NodeList_%D0%B2_Array)

---

```js
let obj = {}

let btnList = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn'))

btnList.forEach(button => {
    let { id, innerText } = button
    obj[id] = innerText
})

console.log(obj)

for (let key in obj) {
    let val = obj[key]
    console.log(`id: ${key} innerText: ${val}`)
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><button id="but1" class="btn">ButtonOne</button></li>
   <li><button id="but2" class="btn">ButtonTwo</button></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Mне удалось найти решение, вот как оно выглядит

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('btn-view')].reduce((a, c, i ) => (a['H' + i + ' - h ' + i] = {name: c.name, id: c.id}, a), {}); console.log(objData);
```